# add jPanels by selecting jCheckBoxes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcheckbox, netbeans-8

As you can see from layout I want to add (or show) `jPanels` by selecting `checkBoxes`. `panelWindow` is enclosed in `jScrollPane`.

```
 + checkBox1  |            jPanel1  |
-------------------------------------
 + checkBox2  |            jPanel2  |
-------------------------------------
 + checkBox3  |            jPanel3  |
-------------------------------------
      ^                       ^
      |                       |
 checkBoxPanel            panelWindow
```

In the case when selected `checkBox2` and `checkBox3`, `panelWindow` shows `jPanel2` and `jPanel3`, so the position of `jPanel1` will be replaced by `jPanel2` and the position of `jPanel2` by `jPanel3`.

```
 + checkBox2  |            jPanel2  |
-------------------------------------
 + checkBox3  |            jPanel3  |
------------------------------------- 
      ^                       ^
      |                       |
 checkBoxPanel            panelWindow
```

Right now I don't have any idea how to achieve this goal. I tried to use CardLayout, but in that case `panelWindow` just switches `jPanels`.

The goal I want to achieve is by selecting several `checkBoxes` show the selected `jPanels` in `panelWindow`. And if the any `checkBoxes` doesn't selected, in that case `panelWindow` is empty.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. You want jPanel1 to be replaced by jPanel2... but where is the checkBox1 in this case? How can you set the jPanel1 to be shown again?

Comment: Post the related code (it seems that except for the functionality you have the layout sorted) so that we can relate to it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @StanislavL, I created a `Map` between the `JCheckBoxes` and the `JPanel`s with an `ItemListener` for showing and hiding the panels.

```
public class PanelShower extends JFrame {

    Map<JCheckBox, JPanel> boxPanelMap = new HashMap<>();
    final int size = 5;

    public PanelShower() {

        JPanel boxesPanel = new JPanel();
        boxesPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxesPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JPanel panelsPanel = new JPanel();
        panelsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelsPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Box " + i);
            checkBox.addItemListener(new SelectionListener());
            boxesPanel.add(checkBox);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));
            panel.setBackground(new Color( (int) (Math.random() * (Math.pow(2, 24) - 1) ) ));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Panel " + i));
            panel.setVisible(false);
            panelsPanel.add(panel);

            boxPanelMap.put(checkBox, panel);
        }

        getContentPane().add(boxesPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        getContentPane().add(panelsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class SelectionListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            (boxPanelMap.get(e.getSource())).setVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new PanelShower();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- The `pack()` call inside the `ItemListener` is necessary just for respecting the preferred size I set for the panels.
- You might want to have the `ItemListener` to be more "type safe" by passing the `JCheckBox` to it in construction:

  ```
  private class SelectionListener implements ItemListener {

      JCheckBox checkBox;

      SelectionListener(JCheckBox checkBox) {

          this.checkBox = checkBox;
      }

      @Override
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

          (boxPanelMap.get(checkBox)).setVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
          pack();
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Create list of pairs checkbox/panel. Add all the pairs to the container(s) but make the panel invisible. Add for each checkbox a listener to show/hide the panel depending on the checkbox's state.